# How do I upgrade from 8.4.2 to 8.4.3?

Tags: 8

I already have Drupal 8.4.2. Now I want to upgrade to 8.4.3 via commandline.

Via Drupal commands or Composer.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way :

```
composer update
drush updb # or update.php via browser
```

Comment: Seems not working already tried

Comment: It does... what did not work ? did you update your composer.json file ? (with 8.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Drush:**

Update Drupal 8 core `drush up drupal`

Update a single module `drush up module_name`

Update only security updates `drush up --security-only`

**Manual Updation:**

http://www.zymphonies.com/blog/update-drupal8-core

Comment: With `drush up drupal` gives `Unable to load class \Drush\VersionControl\Backup ` error

Comment: You can try manual update option also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal Console, then have a look at following command:

```
drupal module:update [arguments] [options]
moup
```

Reference: https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/module-update.html